# Bem names getting too long - best practice

Tags: css, html, naming-conventions, bem

I have the following HTML code, I tend to have a 3 code project identifier at the start

```
<span class="abc-user-overview__header__title"> 
    <span class="abc-user-overview__header__title__name">  
        {{ name }}  
    <span class="abc-user-overview__header__active">true</span>
</span>
```

Although the 'name' element is a child of title, how strict does the naming convention have to be? As I think **abc-user-overview__header__title__name** is too long and would prefer to drop the __title, giving me:

```
<span class="abc-user-overview__header__title"> 
     <span class="abc-user-overview__header__name">  
         {{ name }}  
     <span class="abc-user-overview__header__active"true</span>
</span>
```

Is this valid and acceptable BEM?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Sadly your code is not valid according to BEM convention. This is the official name structure `block-name__elem-name_mod-name_mod-val`.

Here is your code with valid BEM naming:

```
<span class="abc-user-overview__title"> 
    <span class="abc-user-overview__name">{{ name }}</span>
    <span class="abc-user-overview__status abc-user-overview__status_active">true</span>
</span>
```

**Few tips:**

- Avoid naming your blocks according to their content. Try to be generic for blocks that can be reused. For example, let us have a block that represents a list content. On one of the pages we may display News `.news-list`, but on other we may display Products, so reusing block with name `.news-list` with Products inside isnt very nice. In this case a simple class like `.list` will be enough.
- If something can be reused, make it `block`, not an `element`.
- For boolean modifiers, the value is not included in the name.

Full documentation and great examples can be found in the official website: https://en.bem.info/methodology/naming-convention/#naming-rules

Comment: Active is a modifier and the valid class should look like this: `abc-user-overview__status--active`

Comment: @Khazl yes, "active" is exactly a modifier and in my example I'm following the official BEM naming convention. Yours is also valid, but it's just a different convention. Read the official docs from the link in my answer. 

"The modifier value is separated from the modifier name by a single underscore (_)."

Comment: very interesting variant  I don't know about it, thanks you for explaining.
If I use BEM, I have always used this scheme: http://getbem.com/naming/
I think it's much more visually prominent. But well, that's taste and habit.

Comment: @Khazl Both are valid as long as you use them consistently in your project. My example is from BEM creators documentation :)

Answer (score 0):

Those names aren't too long. Sometimes when names get too long it's because you've got too much going on in that page. When I see that in angular (for example) I consider extracting components, then you can chop off the block and half the element name from the existing css classes and replace with a shorter block name. it makes the parent component so much easier to read when you move a lot of unrelated complexity to a different component. Good candidates for this could include

- mobile menus
- containers (anything with responsive widths, padding or icons to collapse or expand some region)
- footers
- complicated widgets that show some stats
- any repeated card with a title, photo, description and hyperlink.

Some of these components might be useful for the whole application, or maybe just for that page. Etc.

Answer (score 0):

Instead of this:

`block-name__elem-name_mod-name_mod-val`

I use this, that's a bit shorter and easier to read:

`blockName-elemName--modName--modVal`

In alternative, you can separate the modificator. Be careful, this may create conflicts if you use mixins:

```
<ul class="blockName">
  <li class="blockName-elemName --first">...</li>
  <li class="blockName-elemName">...</li>
  <li class="blockName-elemName">...</li>
  <li class="blockName-elemName --last">...</li>
</ul>
```